# Lowering batch-size eventually results in PyTorch increasing amount of memory reserved

Tags: memory, nlp, pytorch, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train a model meant for long text classification. I'm using this repo: https://github.com/franbvalero/BERT-long-sentence-classification/tree/optimizer_lstm
But I modified it to work with a different dataset (i.e. I changed the inputs, not anything directly related to the training). I'm also using a different BERT model trained for another language.

The problem I'm facing is that going lower in bath-size increases the amount PyTorch reserves. Using 64 as batch-size results in the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.95 GiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 700.89 MiB already allocated; 5.68 GiB free; 756.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Definitely too high for the capacity available to me; I try 32 instead.

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 10.47 GiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 602.89 MiB already allocated; 5.77 GiB free; 658.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Next 16:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 5.24 GiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 5.78 GiB already allocated; 596.27 MiB free; 5.83 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

At this point the reserved total by PyTorch has sky-rocketed and this trend follows all the way down to a batch-size of 1 where it will try allocate just a few mb but PyTorch will reserve >6 gb.

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 336.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 6.20 GiB already allocated; 138.27 MiB free; 6.26 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I'm a little bit confused as to why this happens. Lowering the batch-size does reduce the memory required in terms of the allocation that is attempted, but it also increases the amount that PyTorch reserves.

Comment: Your model is probably too big to train it on a small GPU with only 8 GB. You should either use a bigger GPU, a smaller architecture, a less memory-consuming architecture and/or enable fp16.